# How do I talk about the sound that leaves make when they break?

Tags: attributive-nouns

How do I talk about the sound that leaves make when they break?
Leaves crumbling down by footstep, or leaves in someone's hand being crushed.

> 1. It's the leaf breaking sound.
> 2. It's the leaves breaking sound.
> 3. It's the sound of leaves breaking.

Are any of these correct? Do I have to say differently?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, Joe Kim. How are the leaves breaking? Are the leaves on the tree, or breaking off the tree, or already on the ground?

Comment: Leaves crumbling down by footstep, or leaves in someone's hand being crushed.

Comment: Dry, fallen leaves make a **rustling** or **crunching** sound when you walk through them.

Comment: Ok then, option 3 is the  correct way of expressing it, but replace 'breaking' with one of the words that Færd has suggested below.

Comment: My answer was irrelevant; sorry. My suggestions were _scrunch_, and the two that TRomano has already given.

Comment: #3 except that leaves don't break. Where did you find such a usage?

Answer (score 1):

The sound you hear when you are walking on dried leaves is a crunching, crackling sound.  [CRUNCHING SOUND made by walking on leaves](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mfYjlJRpNeQ)